# Ulam‘s Liar Game changing number

Tags: coding-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I did some research on Ulams Liar game where person A thinks of a number between 1 and 1 Million and  person B asks Yes/No questions. If person A is allowed to lie once, person B needs 25 questions to find out what number it is.
But what if person A is allowed to change the number during the game?

I found a really good explenation to the first case on this site : 
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5fca/52ce9a847f2a18b78403095dbdce9ed2a07c.pdf

Does anyone have an idea for the second case? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If A loses if he is found to have lied more than once, I don't think it makes any difference if he changes the number.  How can you ever tell if he has changed it?

Comment: If you're interested in the worst case (as you seem to be), why do you want to ask this every other question? If $A$ is allowed to change the number once, you could just ask $20$ questions (e.g. about the $20$ binary digits) to find the number, then ask if they've changed it, and if they have, ask the $20$ questions again, for a total of $40$; and you can't do better than that, since whatever questions you ask they can always wait to change the number until you find it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I got it now :)